# Convergence of the exponential for a densely-defined linear operator on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, exponential-function

Let

- $H$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space
- $D(A)$ be a dense subspace of $H$ and $A$ be a linear operator from $D(A)$ to $H$
- $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an orthonormal basis of $H$ with $$-Ae_n=\lambda_ne_n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\tag 1$$ for some $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq(0,\infty)$ with $$\lambda_{n+1}\ge\lambda_n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\tag 2$$

> Let $t\ge 0$. Is $$e^{-tA}x:=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}e^{-\lambda_nt}\langle x,e_n\rangle_He_n\tag 3$$ a well-defined bounded linear operator on $H$?

The actual question is: Is the series in $(3)$ convergent? By the [comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test#For_series), it's sufficient to show that $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}e^{-\lambda_nt}$ is convergent.

Let $$M:=\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\lambda_n\in(0,\infty]$$ and $$\alpha_n:=\left|\frac{e^{-\lambda_{n+1}t}}{e^{-\lambda_nt}}\right|=e^{-(\lambda_{n+1}-\lambda_n)t}\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N\;.$$ By the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#The_test), it's sufficient to show that $$\alpha_n\le q\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\tag 4$$ for some $q\in[0,1)$. However, by $(2)$ we only obtain $\alpha_n\le 1$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Moreover, if $M<\infty$, then $$\lambda_{n+1}=\lambda_n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\ge N\tag 5$$ for some $N\in\mathbb N$ and hence $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}e^{-\lambda_nt}$ should be divergent.

> So, do we need to assume $M=\infty$? And how do we prove the convergence in that case?

Comment: Are you sure you mean for $A$ to be _bounded_ on $D(A)$ and not unbounded?

Comment: I have deleted my answer because I see inconsistent formulation, you write
$-A e_n=\lambda_n$
and
$e^{-tA}e_n=e^{-t\lambda_n}e_n$. Both cannot be true obviously, and it matters which one you choose.

Comment: If you have $Ae_n=\lambda_n e_n$ where $\lambda_n$ is bounded from below, then $\exp(-t A)$ is well defined on all of $H$ and your series converges.

Comment: @s.harp I'm sorry, I've meant simply "linear operator" (i.e. possibly unbounded). I don't see the inconsistency you've mentioned. I've used the same formulation as in [the definition of $e^{-tA}$ in a book that I'm reading](https://books.google.de/books?id=GX_RAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA101&lpg=PA101&dq=%22has+a+complete+orthonormal+set+of+eigenfunctions%22+%22The+right-hand+side+already+appeared+in%22&source=bl&ots=aikD9fMYqf&sig=nvSVJJIsk53laH4K12QaWK7N0fE&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiaoPymtbTPAhUHPxQKHUkjDKQQ6AEIHDAA).

Comment: in the link you have $Ae_n=\lambda_n$ not $-Ae_n=\lambda_n$, I'll undelete my answer although another answer already exists that says basically the same thing.

Comment: @s.harp But they write that $\color{red}{-}A$ has a complete set of eigenfunctions ... Shouldn't that mean that $-Ae_n=\lambda_ne_n$?

Comment: @s.harp I've thought about what you wrote. If we *formally* apply the series representation of the exponential function in the expression $e^{tA}x$ we obtain $e^{tA}x=\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}e^{t\lambda_k}\langle x,e_k\rangle_He_k$ (under the assumption $Ae_k=\lambda_ke_k$). So, I guess it's simply a misleading formulation in the linked book.

Comment: @0xbadfood sorry for the late reply. You are right, in the link they do write that $-A$ has positive eigenvalues. I think this has to be a typographical error. In part I say this because every sensible definition of $e^{-tA}$ should agree with $\sum_n^\infty (-tA)^n/n!$ whenever the latter can be defined. In the case here you have that the definition $e^{-tA}$ actually agrees with $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (tA)^n/n!$. The convergence of the sum is to be taken in the strong operator topology, in this (special) case the sum will converge for all $t≥0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda_n$ be a monotone increasing sequence, for every $x\in H$ you have $\langle x, e_n\rangle$ is square summable. Since $\lambda_n$ is monotone increasing you have $|e^{-t\lambda_n}|≤|e^{-t\lambda_0}|$ and for that reason $e^{-t \lambda_n}\langle x, e_n\rangle$ is square summable, being majorised by the square summable $e^{-t\lambda_0 } |\langle x, e_n\rangle|$.

For this reason the map $$e^{-tA}: H\to H, \qquad x\mapsto \sum_n e^{-t \lambda_n} \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n$$
is well defined. Linearity is trivial also.

Boundedness of the $\lambda_n$ is not necessary, you only need that the operator be **bounded from below**.

Note that if $A$ is bounded on $D(A)$ it extends to a bounded operator on $H$ and also that $e^{-t A}:=\sum_n (-tA)^n/n!$ is well defined and converges in operator norm.

Answer (score 3):

Because your set $\{ e_n \}$ is orthonormal, then $\sum_{n}\alpha_n e_n$ converges in $H$ iff $\sum_{n}|\alpha_n|^2 < \infty$. In this case,
$$
           \|\sum_{n} e^{-\lambda_n t}\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n\|^2 = \sum_{n}e^{-2\lambda_n t}|\langle x,e_n\rangle|^2 \le \sum_{n}|\langle x,e_n\rangle|^2=\|x\|^2.
$$
So your operator $e^{-tA}$ is a bounded operator with $\|e^{-tA}\| \le 1$ for all $t > 0$. In fact, $\|e^{-tA}\| \le e^{-\lambda_1 t}$. And, you do not need to assume that the $\lambda_n \le M$ for all $n$ and some $M$.

Comment: There is something wrong with the left-hand side of your inequality, isn't it? In light of your preceding sentence, shouldn't it be $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left|e^{-\lambda_nt}\langle x,e_n\rangle_H\right|$? In any case, I don't see that the first equality holds.

Comment: @0xbadf00d : The square of the norm is the sum of the squares of the coefficients of the orthonormal basis elements.